# table top gaming: how make character walk from one house to another, passing through every house in between?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I just start to learn coding with Swift last month. This is my second personal project.
I'm creating a table top game like "Monopoly" or something. Here an image of my prototype:[my table top board game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAKGT.png)

I'm using a arc4random for the dices and moving the character/player with this code:

```
if positionPlayer1 == 1 {
        let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        player1.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(-66, y: 0, duration: 1))
        }

    } else if positionPlayer1 == 2 {
        let time = dispatch_time(dispatch_time_t(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW), 1 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        player1.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(-44, y: 0, duration: 1))
        }
```

I also tried :

```
player1.runAction(SKAction.moveByX(-66, y: 0, duration: 1))
        sleep(1)
```

The problem is: the character waits the total time e runs directly to the final position. Let's say the dice give an 6, the character waits for 6 seconds and runs to the last position. This is not a problem on a straight line, but if the movement pass through a corner, the character cuts in diagonal directly to the final position instead of pass through every house as intended.
Any help will be appreciated.

Edit: I decided to try physics. I created a lot of SKSpriteNode "walls". To all nodes I'm using:

```
squareBlock02.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    squareBlock02.physicsBody?.pinned = true
    squareBlock02.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
```

The result is that the player hits those walls and move them. I tried mass, density... nothing prevents the player from push all walls from its way.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all people that try to help.

I finally found the answer at this site: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/02/Game-development-tutorial-Swift-and-SpriteKit-Part-4-Actions.aspx

```
import SpriteKit

// Solution found: http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/07/02/Game-development-tutorial-Swift-and-SpriteKit-Part-4-Actions.aspx

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Player_01-2.png")

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        /* Setup your scene here */
        player.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x:0.5,y:0.5)
        player.position = CGPoint(x:view.bounds.midX,y:view.bounds.midY)
        self.addChild(player)
        doStuff()
    }

    func doStuff(){
        var actions = Array<SKAction>()
        actions.append(SKAction.moveTo(CGPoint(x:300,y:300), duration: 1))
        actions.append(SKAction.rotateByAngle(6.28, duration: 1))
        actions.append(SKAction.moveBy(CGVector(dx: 150,dy: 0), duration: 1))
        actions.append(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(SKColor.redColor(), colorBlendFactor: 0.5, duration: 1))
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence(actions)
        player.runAction(sequence)
    }

}
```